# quickfixJ Getting Session settings from the session object

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I would like to customize the sent Login message in the toAdmin method by adding the Username and Password values from the current session settings. Something like that:

```
@Override
public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionId) {
    Header header = message.getHeader();
    if (!header.isSetField(MsgType.FIELD) || !header.getString(MsgType.FIELD).equals(MsgType.LOGON))
    {
        // not a logon message: do not modify it
        return;
    }

    Session session = Session.lookupSession(sessionId);           

    message.setField(new Username(seesion.getSettingValue("Username")));
    message.setField(new Password(seesion.getSettingValue("Password")));
}
```

The `getSettingValue` method doesn't exist. Is there any way to do this in quickfixJ? BTW this is possible in quickfixn.

Comment: Starting with QuickFIX/J 2.2.0 you are able to pass `LogonTag` session settings to have these tags set on the Logon message that is sent out. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62445873/4962355

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to define custom Username/Password settings in your config file.  (QF does not have these built-in.)

This link will show you how to use custom settings.
http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/Using+Custom+Settings
(Ignore the bit in the prose about `getSessionSettings()`; this method does not appear to actually exist in the current build.)

**In case that page goes down, in a nutshell the process is this:**

Somehow give your MessageCracker app a reference to your `SessionSettings` object (whether by constructor or get/set or however).

In your `toAdmin()`, do something like this:

```
final String msgType = msg.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
if(MsgType.LOGON.compareTo(msgType) == 0)
{
    msg.setString(quickfix.fields.Username.FIELD,
      mySettings.getString(sessionID, "Username");
    msg.setString(quickfix.fields.Password.FIELD,
      mySettings.getString(sessionID, "Password");
}
```

(I haven't compiled this code; please let me know if I have a syntax error and I'll fix it.)

I literally just added the C# equivalent to the [QF/n User FAQ](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/wiki/User-FAQ) yesterday.  You must be on the QF/n mail list, or else just have really great timing.

(I should probably add this to the [QF/j User FAQ](http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/User+FAQ) as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are looking in the right direction. I just checked the [Session](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/)  class in the QuickfixJ documentation. It doesn't have any data members **username** or **password**. So you cannot extract any values, which it doesn't contain.

Or are you using your special version of Session class ? I don't believe Session should be holding any of those data either, it is unecessary and open to malicious use. I am not sure how the same side can have multiple userid and passwords to connect to another side(same one and I am assuming so because you are trying to use the same session id to fetch the user id and password), opens up all issues once again.

So if you have a single userid/password, better take it from your DB or other source you might be using rather than trying to fetch it from the session.

Comment: My question here is more about getting session settings from the session object. let's put username/pwd aside, how to get LongonTimeout or HeartBtInt from the session object? You can do so in .NET as I mentioned. Is there a way to get any session settings from a session object?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this in QuickFIX/J. Take a look at the QFJ wiki for an [example](http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/Using+Custom+Settings). Rather than accessing the session settings through the `Session` you can provide a `SessionSettings` instance to your `Application` implementation and then use that object to get your custom settings.