# How to add 58/Text into Logon message using QuickFIX

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I need to send tag **58=something** in 35=A (logon message) in FIX4.4.
How should I configure .cfg file of QuickFIX tool to have this tag sent by the tool?

Comment: Which variant do you use? For C++ or Java? You tagged "quickfixj" but write QuickFIX (which is C++). If QuickFIX/J, which version exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't use the config file for that.  (Not sure where you got that idea.)

Logon is an admin message, so you would do it in the `toAdmin()` callback.  This callback handles *all* admin messages, though, so you need to write a check to make sure you only add it to Logon.

You could put this code in `toAdmin()`:

```java
final String msgType = msg.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
if(MsgType.LOGON.compareTo(msgType) == 0)
{
    // "Text" is the name of field 58
    // That constant literally resolves to int 58.
    msg.setString(quickfix.fields.Text.FIELD, "razzledazzle");
}
```

(I'm assuming QF/j, but the code would be similar for any QF.)

Comment: Maybe the idea for the config comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62445873/4962355 :) But only working in QFJ.

Comment: Ha, interesting.